# How to overcome pointless C++ compiler warnings elegantly?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings

This question is not bound to any specific compiler warning, the following is just an example.

Currently when I want a loop that checks an exit condition inside:

```
 while( true ) {
    doSomething();
    if( condition() ) {
       break;
    }
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

I can't just write that in Visual C++ - it will emit a C4127 `conditional expression is constant` warning. The compiler will wave it in my face although it's quite obvious that `while(true)` can't have been written accidentially.

Suppose I want code that compiles without warnings. There're *workarounds* at my service.

*Workaround one* is to use `for(;;)` but it feels stupid - why would I want that weird thing instead of concise elegant idiomatic `while(true)`? *Workaround two* is to use `#pragma warning( suppress)` before `while( true )` line but it adds a huge banner that is twice as big as the `while`-statement itself. *Workaround three* is to disable C4127 for the entire project (I've seen it done in a real project) but then all possible useful instances of C4127 are also disabled.

Is there any elegant way to get rid of a pointless warning?

Comment: `for(;;) ` says `forever..`

Comment: g++ compiles it without warnings with maximum possible error level. Is this windows only question?

Comment: I agree with @PrinceJohnWesley: `for(;;)` is idiomatic.

Comment: `volatile int VeryTrue = 1; ... while(VeryTrue) ... ;` But I just stick with for(;;). Everyone writing in C(++) must know this idiom anyway.

Comment: @ern0 That's an amazing and probably infeasible amount of trouble to go to just to avoid a compiler warning because you have some pointless inhibition about writing 100% equivalent code that doesn't generate the warning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/q/1946445/72178](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1946445/72178)

Comment: @ks1322: That question is specific to that exact warning and I've read it already.

Answer (score 28):

I'd write `for(;;)` because that's idiomatic.

Newer versions of Visual C++ are not as idiot as earlier versions were wrt. warnings. Visual C++ 10.0 compiles code that uses `<windows.h>`, at warning level 4, no warnings.

But if you want to turn off Visual C++ sillywarnings, take a look at my old [anti-sillywarnings header](http://alfps.wordpress.com/the-no_sillywarnings_please-h-file/), which was created with input from the [comp.lang.c++] community.

Comment: windows.h is compiled without warnings because it is stuffed with `#pragma warning(disable)` inside.

Comment: I like the anti-silly warning header, although some of them don't look *that* silly...

Comment: @jbat100: What amazes me most is that warnings 4510-4513 look very similar to warnings 4623-4626 which I didn't quite realize before.

Answer (score 11):

I'd go with `for(;;)` even without that warning. It's not stupid: it's a loop with no condition, which is exactly what you want to express.

That seems more logical to me than using a while loop and testing that true is still true each time round the loop (of course the compiler will optimize away this test, so it won't actually affect performance).

Comment: -1 because its addressing only an *example* given by the OP and not the actual question about strategies to deal with all *pointless* warnings

Comment: @Will In fact the question is specifically about *one* warning (C4127) in *one compiler. Upvoting.

Comment: @EJP "This question is not bound to any specific compiler warning, the following is just an example." ... "Is there any elegant way to get rid of a pointless warning?"

Comment: @Will I can read, thanks, including the parts you didn't quote.

Answer (score 6):

What could be -- realistically implementable -- *more* elegant that a single line of:

```
 #pragma warning ( suppress : 4127 )
```

(*I can't* use this as I'm still on VS2005 where this [doesn't work for all warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).)

Certainly, for your case `for(;;)` could be the pragmatic approach, but in general

> How to overcome **pointless** C++ compiler warnings elegantly?

I'd say [disable them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133615/how-to-overcome-pointless-c-compiler-warnings-elegantly/8133706#8133706) [project wide](http://alfps.wordpress.com/the-no_sillywarnings_please-h-file/). (there pointless after all). And, to variate

> How to overcome **false-positve** C++ compiler warnings elegantly?

I'd say, a *single* preprocessor line seems quite OK already.

Comment: What's *a single line preprocessor construct*?

Comment: @sharptooth - I was referring to the fact that you only need one line to express your intent of disabling the warning. On VS2005 you have to fiddle with several lines of push/disable/pop

Answer (score 3):

My philosophy is that if you make the compiler suppress warnings, put a comment in there and tell why.  Even if you think it's silly.
Pragma stands out and is visible.  It's a fine comment in your code.

When you start skipping comments when suppressing warnings based on your idea on how silly it is, you are heading for potential trouble.  Another person working on your code after a year might change it, have trouble and waste precious time hunting it down.

Btw, you are looking for a way of suppressing the warnings without either

- Use pragma
- Use ugly code
- Use project wide suppression

That would be a very hidden suppression method.

If you don't like the look of pragma, use

```
bool alwaysTrue = true; // to prevent compiler warning C4127
while (alwaysTrue) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use while(true, 1) to suppress this warning.

Answer (score -1):

Do some funny token pasting: if you can swap

```
while(true)
```

for

```
While(true)
```

then just do the following:

```
#define while_true for( ;; )
#define While(a) while_##a
```

Comment: I do not see why. The behaviour of  `for(;;)` is pure convention. It should be equivalen to `while()` that does not compile. So I hid the ugly `for(;;)`, changed the `while` a bit, to keep close to the original code.

Comment: Well, `for(;;)` is a widely used overengineered construct and what you suggest is a newly introduced overengineered construct.

Comment: The advice to install Linux and use GCC looks even well comparing to this answer.

Comment: Downvote me to death, nobody provided a working example to overcome your problem. 
for is correct but ugly to some - I just hid it. 
Disabling warning may make you miss errors (more usually typos I did a bit of stats (on OSS) and about 2/3 of coders use for(;;) whereas the other 1/3 goes for while(true). 
for has a distinct C-ish flavour, that some may find disgusting (it reminds me of Numerical Recipes...)

Comment: I really laughed aloud! Thanks @reder! Let's spice those codes!

Answer (score -2):

There are many cases in which satisfactory code behaves as intended yet generates a slew of warnings. This is why they're *warnings* rather than errors. The fact that they annoy you is good: warnings are intended to modify your behaviour. You are supposed to mend your ways, not sweep them under the carpet.

The example loop from the question could be written like this:

```
for (; testExitCondition();) 
  doSomething();
```

In more sophisticated cases the loop counter can be used as the state of a state machine (each action is required to update *state*):

```
for (int state = stateBegin; state == stateTerminate;) 
{
  switch (state) 
  {
    case stateBegin:
      //elaborate setup
      break;
    case state_1: 
      doSomething_1();
      break;
    case state_2: 
      doSomething_2();
      break;
    case state_n: 
      doSomething_n();
      break;
}
```

---

My favourite way to avoid pointless C++ warnings is to use C# :)

Admittedly this produces a slew of pointless C# warnings but nothing's perfect.

Gosh, look at the negative votes. Proof that C++ damages your sense of humour.

Comment: In this case the answer was already at the bottom of the list. Further downvotes serve only to demonstrate humourless pettiness. I treated this question as a joke because it is self-evident that the way to avoid warnings is to write code in such a way that they are not triggered. In C# it is possible to suppress a warning with attributes, globally or right down to a specific member. People rarely use this because sweeping hiding warnings is a bad idea.