# why c language needs this for(; ;) loop?

Tags: c, gcc

why c language needs this `for(; ;)` loop ? It is actually an infinite loop and `while(1)` also infinite loop. My question is that which one we should use ? I want to know which one is more efficient according to compiler point of view?

Comment: Both are same & both do the same work- infinite loop.

Comment: No difference in the effect, I consider `while(1)` clearer.

Comment: Generally `while(TRUE)` is more quickly/cleanly understood.

Comment: exactly the same - personally I prefer `while(1)`, it just looks neater..

Comment: Legend says it's for historical reasons http://stackoverflow.com/q/8292305/57428

Comment: FWIW, `do { ... } while(FALSE);` can also be quite useful, to allow you to insert (using `break`) "GOTOs" to the end of the block.  Useful for a "filter" that tests some data with multiple sequential validity tests.

Comment: One point is also that any `for` cycle can be substituted with an equivalent `while` cycle (and initialization), so it's pretty logical that you can find two equivalent ways of doing an infinite cycle.

Comment: It's not about need. It's about C allowing empty statements, such as `;;;` or `if (1) { } else { }`. In this particular case C allows any or all of the traditionally used expressions/statements or loop body in `for (statement1;expression1;statement3) body4` to be missing. Also it would be very hard to generate a language where there's always only one way to accomplish some programming task...

Answer (score 3):

Both are same. I believe infinite loops are needed when you want to break on a certain condition which the executing code knows only once it enters the loop.

For me this looks more intuitive and easier:

```
while(1) {}
while(true) {}
```

Remember even this is an infinite loop :

```
// just don't provide the condition 
for(int i=0; ;i++) // don't mind the syntax as I don't belong to C
```

Answer (score 0):

Whichever fits your needs. Both do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For an infinite loop, both do the same thing, but `for` and `while` are used for different things, and are not generally interchangeable.