# Where is the source code for the earliest C compilers?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, history

This is not a request such as "which tool can I use to do ...?", which does not belong on stackoverflow.

In several questions answers that seem to have quite some authority refer to analysis of source code of early compilers, e.g.:

- [Why was the switch statement designed to need a break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252489/why-was-the-switch-statement-designed-to-need-a-break) where is referred to the `Sun ANSI C compiler front end` by Peter van der Linden.
- [Is "for(;;)" idiom for infinite loop correctly attributed to PDP-11 C compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292305/is-for-idiom-for-infinite-loop-correctly-attributed-to-pdp-11-c-compiler) where a question is asked about the `for(;;)` idiom w.r.t. "an early PDP-11" compiler
- [Code for malloc and free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485586/code-for-malloc-and-free) refers to contemporary implementation of `glibc`

Also wikipedia describes several old compilers such as:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_C_Compiler by Stephen C. Johnson of Bell labs in mid seventies
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amsterdam_Compiler_Kit by Andrew Tanenbaum in early eighties (but not open-source of course, or we wouldn't have had `gcc`)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection by Richard Stallman in 1987

However, there are no references to the earliest versions that are of greatest historic interest!

Considering that the **truth lies in the code** it would be great to know where to find the source code for the earliest C compilers.

Comment: What is the connection between "contemporary glibc" and "the earliest C compilers"?

Comment: It may not be "which tool can I use to do ...?" but it's still "help me find X" which is also off-topic.

Comment: Read [The Development of the C Language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html), and [Reflections on Trusting Trust](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html). Anyway, the earliest C compilers are proprietary, and belong to Bell Labs.

Comment: @jalf. True. It was just an illustration that referring to the code is a common practice. I will find more question that refer to historic code, but I am afraid this question will be closed anyway... :(

Comment: You might be able an early version of the compiler in the [UNIX v6 source code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_6_Unix).

Comment: The truth lies in the *language specification*; the compiler simply implements that specification.  It's no secret that Ritchie made some mistakes in the design of C, but those mistakes only became apparent after C was in fairly widespread use.  Some of those issues were addressed by the 1989 standard, but it couldn't fix everything (such as switch statement semantics), at least not without breaking a *lot* of legacy code.

Comment: Thanks @jxh! Pity that this question will generate "opinionated answers and spam". I wouldn't expect that, but I respect the policies.

Comment: The source code history for GCC starts [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/?pathrev=1), in about 1989. That's not actually the beginning of the project, just the date it was first imported into RCS. Unfortunately, due to the way RCS was converted to CVS, and then CVS was converted to Subversion (and next into GIT), the initial revisions just import one file at a time, so it's a longer job than I want to do to find out what revision number holds the first complete, buildable source base.

Comment: I found also [Ritchies text](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/primevalC.html) about DECtapes found by Paul Vixie and Keith Bostic. The code is at the bottom of that page. Ritchie dates his code at around 1972-1973.

Comment: I'd ask folks at the Computer Museum in the Bay Area whether they had access to early versions.  They collect all kinds of stuff. See http://www.computerhistory.org/