# How to disable C4127 for do {} while(false)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-warnings, c4127

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++: How to use the do-while(0); construct without compiler warnings like C4127?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946445/c-c-how-to-use-the-do-while0-construct-without-compiler-warnings-like-c412)

```
//file error.h

        #define FAIL(message) \
        do { \
            std::ostringstream ossMsg; \
            ossMsg << message; \
            THROW_EXCEPTION(ossMsg.str());\
        } while (false)


//main.cpp

...

FAIL("invalid parameters"); // <<< warning C4127: conditional expression is constant    

...
```

As you can see the warning is related to the `do {} while(false)`.

I can only figure out the following way to disable the warning:

```
        #pragma warning( push )
        #pragma warning( disable : 4127 )
        FAIL("invalid parameters");
        #pragma warning( pop )
```

but I don't like this solution.

I also tried to put those macro in error.h without effect.

Any comments on how to suppress this warning in a decent way?

Thank you

Comment: I'm sure you can pass command line arg to compiler

Comment: Summary: as answered in that other question, disable the warning. Not just locally with `#pragma warning`, but leave it disabled altogether.

Comment: Ok, but why not to leave just scope without `do...while`?

Comment: @Lol4t0 It's a common construct that makes `FAIL(...)` require an extra semicolon to form a full statement. It's to allow `if (...) FAIL(...); else` and have the `else` belong to the `if`.

Answer (score 6):

The warning is due to the `while(false)`. This [site](http://cnicholson.net/2009/03/stupid-c-tricks-dowhile0-and-c4127/) gives an example of how to workaround this problem. Example from site (you'll have to re-work it for your code):

```
#define MULTI_LINE_MACRO_BEGIN do {  
#define MULTI_LINE_MACRO_END \  
    __pragma(warning(push)) \  
    __pragma(warning(disable:4127)) \  
    } while(0) \  
    __pragma(warning(pop))

#define MULTI_LINE_MACRO \  
        MULTI_LINE_MACRO_BEGIN \  
            std::printf("Hello "); \  
            std::printf("world!\n"); \  
        MULTI_LINE_MACRO_END
```

Just insert your code between the BEGIN and END:

```
#define FAIL(message) \  
    MULTI_LINE_MACRO_BEGIN \  
        std::ostringstream ossMsg; \
        ossMsg << message; \
        THROW_EXCEPTION(ossMsg.str());\  
    MULTI_LINE_MACRO_END
```

Comment: You really should not have a link as your answer.

Comment: I got `error C2017: illegal escape sequence` for the usage of `__pragma`. MSVS 2010 cannot give it right.

Comment: @q0987: Not sure why.. it's a valid keyword (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx)

Comment: Yes, it is valid but the compiler complains and I saw similar posts through google

Comment: @q0987: make sure there are no spaces or tabs after the `'\'` characters that are supposed to indicate line continuation.

Comment: This is a better answer than the one in the duplicate.

Comment: @MichaelBurr If the code is meant to be usable on other compilers too, it isn't. If the code is not meant to be used with anything other than VC++, opinions will still vary, but many people will agree with you. (Actually, this is one of the answers in the original already, although this has extra macros.)

Answer (score 1):

1)  Why not just `THROW_EXCEPTION("invalid parameters")`?
2)  `while(true)` and `break` at the end?

Comment: +1 - I don't know why this got voted down, it is an easy and clean fix and if you put a comments in there explaining why you did it then it will be clear.

Comment: @Caesar: Because it doesn't address the problem of using do/while(false) with multi-line processor directives and the associated warning.

Comment: @0A0D Maybe I miss understood the OP, but from my understanding is that he wanted a cleaner code. This is way cleaner then the example you gave and the functionality is the same.

Comment: @Caesar: No, he wanted to know a better way to disable the warning without all the clutter, but still wanted the multi-line macro.

Comment: fwiw, I'm cool with the logic behind the downvote, but on the off-chance this helped the OP left it as an answer anyway.

Comment: and this won't break in teh same way as just using scope blocks will? Edit - nevermind, while(true) has the same warning as while(false)