# C++ void cast and operator comma in a #define

Tags: c++, macros

I found this while reading some source code.

```
 #define MACRO(x)  if((void) 0, (x)); else some_func();
```

I don't fully understand the reasons behind that operator comma and the void cast. This has probably something to do with macro protection, I know that `(void)0` is used sometimes to protect cascading `else`s in macros such as in `if(...) then foo(); else (void)0`.

Any ideas of why operator comma is there?

**edit:** I'm starting to think this has something to do with the [owl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1853723/55935) `(0,0)`.

Comment: Are you sure that even compiles?

Comment: @ronag: yes it compiles. the cast to void is a nice trick if you like to write `return f();` from a void function when `f` is not void.

Comment: I am curious to know if it is equivalent to `#define MACRO(X) if(!(x))  { some_func() }`

Comment: @ArunSaha: That's not. This: `MACRO(x) else ...` will compile with your macro but not with the original.

Comment: @ybungalobill: I see, Thanks. Not sure, but can that be fixed by wrapping my version inside a `do { ... } while ( 0 );`? (Sigh! I am so bad with macros!)

Comment: @ArunSaha: Yes, just pointed out that they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would guess that the trick is used to prevent the user from declaring variables in the `if` condition. As you probably know, in C++ it is legal to do this

```
if (int i = some_func()) {
   // you can use `i` here
}
else  {
   // and you can use `i` here
}
```

The use of comma operator in that definition will prevent macro usage like

```
MACRO(int i = some_func());
```

and force the user to use only *expressions* as argument.

Comment: You mean `i` instead of `x`, yes?

Comment: That what I though, but to quote Charles, it's true here too: "... what ((void)0,x) is supposed to guard against that a simple extra pair of parentheses wouldn't if((x)); else some_func();".

Comment: @ybungalobill: Yeah, that's right... And extra `()` would solve it in a much simpler way.

Answer (score 4):

The void conversion there is definitely to prevent calling an overloaded `operator ,` since you can't overload with a void parameter. This guarantees that `(void)0,` has no effect.

Why the comma operator is there? A good question. I really don't know.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain in more detail what `((void)0,x)` is supposed to guard against that a simple extra pair of parentheses wouldn't `if((x)); else some_func();` ?

Answer (score 2):

This *looks* a bit as if somebody may have started with some code that included an `assert`, pre-processed it, and turned the result into a macro. When `NDEBUG` is defined, `assert` has to turn into nearly nothing -- but, syntactically, still has to produce some placeholder code. For example, you're allowed to use it in a situation like:

```
assert(x), *x = 1;
```

When you compile this with `NDEBUG` defined, it still needs to compile, but the `assert` shouldn't do anything. To support that, `assert` is typically defined something like this:

```
#undef assert
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define assert(x) ((void)0)
#else
#define assert(x) ((!!x) || __failassert(x, __FILE__, __LINE__))
#endif
```

So, if somebody started with code like above, and then looked at the preprocessed version (with NDEBUG defined), they'd see something like:

```
((void *)0), *x = 1;
```

...and if they didn't understand the code very well, they might think that `((void)0)` really meant/accomplished something.

Comment: Good reasoning, but I'm not sure that is the real reason.

Comment: I'm not *sure* it's the real reason either -- in fact, probably nobody but the original author can do anything but guess, and even he may not remember for sure either...

Comment: this "crazy" works with original MACRO : #define CRAZY 0));if((1

Comment: @user396672, yes but is that the real reason? AndreyT's explanation sounds at least *halfway* reasonable, but this is working awfully hard to prevent something that it's hard to imagine anybody writing in the first place.